# Function to toggle 'list-bookmark' in the style of Neotree or speedbar

Tags: window-splitting

I modified this function:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (defun toggle-bookmark-list ()
    "Toggles between bookmark list and current buffer "
    (interactive)
    (if (string= (buffer-name) "*Bookmark List*")
    (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer (current-buffer)))
      (if (get-buffer "*Bookmark List*")
      (switch-to-buffer "*Bookmark List*")
    (progn
      (list-bookmarks (getenv "Book Mark"))
      ))))
  (global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'toggle-bookmark-list)
#+END_SRC
```

When I press `F6`, it will open a `list-bookmark` buffer right where my current buffer is. I can then toggle it on and off. For example:
Original:

```
   | buffer 1 | buffer 2 |
   |          |          |
   |          |          |
```

After pressing `F6`:

```
   | list-bookmark | buffer 2 |
   |               |          |
   |               |          |
```

Is there a way to have it display on the side like Neotree, instead of replacing current buffer? 
What I mean is:

Original:

```
   | buffer 1 | buffer 2 |
   |          |          |
   |          |          |
```

After pressing `F6`:

```
   | list-bookmark     | buffer 1 | buffer 2 |
   |                   |          |          |
   |                   |          |          |
```

So it would appear as a separate buffer and I can specify it to appear where I want (always on the left of buffer 1 in this case).

Comment: This is essentially a question about windows, not buffers.

Comment: Please consider indenting your code properly.